# How to get key and value with yq V4.x.x

Tags: bash, yq

We have upgraded yq from version 3.x.x to version 4.x.x and there is a part that does not work the same when getting a key value from the following structure:

```
key: a
value:
  enabled: true
  project: ../../a
  version: v1.1.1
  persistence: true
key: b
value:
  enabled: true
  project: ../../b
  version: v1.1.1
  persistence: true
key: c
value:
  enabled: true
  project: ../../c
  version: v1.1.1
  persistence: false
```

With the following yq command I would get the following

```
"a": true, "b": true, "c": false
```

This is the command

```
yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.enabled == true) .key, .value.persistence' manifest.yml
```

and now the command returns this

```
a
b
c
null
```

I have recently started using yq and I really can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here. First, I think the data structure you've presented in your question is erroneous; looking at the filter you're trying to run, I think the original data structure looks like this:

```
applications:
  a:
    enabled: true
    project: ../../a
    version: v1.1.1
    persistence: true
  b:
    enabled: true
    project: ../../b
    version: v1.1.1
    persistence: true
  c:
    enabled: true
    project: ../../c
    version: v1.1.1
    persistence: false
```

If we apply your filter using [`kislyuk/yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), then we see the following output:

```
"a"
true
"b"
true
"c"
false
```

On the other hand, we if use [`mikefarah/yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), we get:

```
a
b
c
null
```

This is because these two commands are *different*. The first is a simple Python wrapper for the `jq` command, whereas the second is a standalone Go binary. They support different syntax.

You cannot "upgrade" from the `kislyuk` version (latest version: `3.1.0`) to the `mikefarah` version (latest version: 4.30.8).

Comment: You are absolutely right the security team passed mikefarah/yq 4.x.x, in this case we are forced to use it.

How could I get the same result with mikefarah/yq? We use this in gitlab runners.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're yaml is actually what @larks has corrected to, then the expression you need is:

```bash
yq '.applications | with_entries(select(.value.enabled == true) | .value = .value.persistence)' file.yaml
```

Explanation:

- delve into `.applications`
- `with_entries` allows us to modify the map entries via `.key` and `.value` (see https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/entries#use-with_entries-to-filter-the-map)
- `select(.value.enabled == true)` select the enabled entries
- `.value = .value.persistence` use the `persistence` property as the new map value

Disclaimer: I wrote yq